# How to open link outside native facebook app on iOS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

After someone shares a link on our fanpage, a user clics on it and the link is opened inside the Native Facebook App on iOS.

Unfortunatley, this is messing up my website's behaviour.

After clicking th link inside the Facebook App, Facebook App opens the URL site.com. Site.com detects a mobile user and redirects to m.site.com. m.site.com is the one that is not working correctly. Particularly, Facebook connect, and a few page elements that are incorrectly aligned.

Is there something I can do to open m.site.com outside Facebook App in iOS?

Currently, I have a Response.Redirect(http://m.site.com).

Also tried window.top.location.href = "http://m.site.com"; but it did not work. It stays inside Facebook iOS App.

I'm using an iPhone 4s, ASP.NET (NOT MVC) and Facebook C# SDK on both my normal site and mobile site.

What I imagine needs to be done, is modify my site.com code to tell the iOS Facebook App to open the mobile site (m.site.com) on safari.